# ATMEL Xmega ADC Input impedance

Tags: adc, voltage-divider

I need to read a 0-6V buffered analog signal from a sensor with the ATXMega256A3BU ADC. With an external voltage reference I can measure voltage level up to about 3V. I'm going to realize a voltage divider but I need some help in finding the correct equivalent resistance of the voltage divider ( R1||R2 ) that is the voltage divider output inpedence.
Atmel says that in the worst case the ADC input resistance Rchannel is 4.5k and the S&H capacitor Csample is 5 pF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ADC characteristics can be found in the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8362-8-and-16bit-AVR-microcontroller-ATxmega256A3BU_datasheet.pdf)

[image]

There is a specific application note from Atmel for Xmega ADC [Using the Atmel AVR XMEGA ADC](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8032-Using-the-Atmel-AVR-XMEGA-ADC_Application-Note_AVR1300.pdf).
If you refer to section 1.8 there is an explanation of how the output impedance of the circuit that feeds the ADC affects the conversion speed:

[image]

The lower the sampling frequency the higher output impedance you can use for the  divider. If you want to use a universal value that can work for a wide range of sampling frequencies then you can go for about 1k or so.

Comment: Thanks, I need to observe a slow signal so is not a problem to have a low sample rate. I don't know if there are critical values for the input impedance of the ADC. On the application note i read that an high impedance input can afflict the measure because of the high time of charge. With a low impedance we have a higher power consumption. But what values ​​are considered high or low?

Comment: And.. You suggested me a voltage divider with two 1k resistors or a voltage divider with R1||R2 of about 1k? The source impedance is R1||R2.

Comment: @Maicol The x axis of the graph is the output impedance of the divider and as you can see for about 1k (1E+3) you can use up to 2000ksamples and get correct results (proper charge of the S&H capacitor) but if you don't need that high frequency you can go with much higher impedance. If you set the impedance to 100k then you can go up to 100ksamples.

Comment: can you confirm me that in a voltage divider the output impedance is R1||R2? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @Maicol Yes, the impedance is R1||R2